# PHP echo the equivalent of CR LF of Notepad

Tags: php, encoding

I need to export some data using PHP and for each line I'm adding a `\r\n`. When I open the exported data file that I downloaded, I see that the `\r\n` is interpreted as [LF] in Notepad.

But the application in which I open the file doesn't read the [LF] as a new line.

Now if I do a [CR][LF] in Notepad, the application can read the [CR][LF] as a new line.

How can I echo the equivalent of [CR][LF] with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved: the string was passed in the POST parameter. Removing the \r.

You just have to do a `str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $...);`.

Answer (score 31):

It's as simple as doing:

```
echo "\r\n";
```

**(note the double quotes)**

Comment: @netcoder - note my comment about double quotes... OP says nothing about that

Comment: Sorry for the long time to answer, indeed I already do a "\r\n" and in notepad when I show the specials characters there is only [LF]. Maybe because my file uses ANSI encoding ?

Answer (score 7):

Do `echo PHP_EOL;`

That way it'll always display the correct linefeed/carriage return combination that's valid for the system you're on, since not all OSes use the same [newline convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). (More information: [PHP global constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).)

Comment: PHP_EOL is valid for the system the __server__ is on, not necessarily for the system that the file is subsequently opened on

Comment: Its the same. Only LF and if I open the file in bloc-note there is no line skiping. As I said maybe due to the encoding ? The php file printing the  \r\n is in ANSI.