# many whitespaces in string after reading of database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the a textarea with the following value:

[image]

I save this value with php into my mysql database.
The result looks like this via phpmyadmin:

[image]

Now, I send a query with php to get the result and to show this text like this, to show it with line breaks:

```
<? echo nl2br($row->text); ?>
```

But the result will shown many withspaces. here the source code:
[image]

Where is my fault? :/

Comment: as described here information can get lost, especially when diffferent systems are involved. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260592/5193536 so check what characters do you actually hgave in your text at the end before echoing them

Answer (score 0):

> The result looks like this via phpmyadmin

phpadmin ist a webpage with html, it doesn't show consecutive blanks.

> Where is my fault? :/

Somewhere between reading it out of the textarea, writing it into the database and reading it back from there.

Steps to track your problem.

What is transferred from the textarea to the server?
Check how the value is in your database.
Output the length of this string to get a simple idea of what *really* is in the database.

Then if you know if the string already got wrong into the database or the error occurs only when reading it, you can go on looking at this particular place.

Comment: `<? echo strlen($row->text); ?>`  = Result 34 - it seems to bee correctly

Comment: Then you have strange behavior in your output. First of all, what is the second picture in your original posting? Is that HTML source? Why are the " there?

Comment: this is the output of the firefox developer console (source code)

Comment: Then look at how you generate this HTML code and where the formatting comes from.